# WebP-wrapper for ASP.NET: location for DLL files

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, dll

Yesterday I came across a [WebP-wrapper](https://github.com/JosePineiro/WebP-wrapper) solutution that I want to use for my ASP.NET (4.8) application. I placed the two DLL files (libwebp_x64.dll and libwebp_x86.dll) in the /bin folder of my application and the translated* WebPWrapper.cs into the /App_Code folder. When I try to run a simple example:

```
Sub myConvert()
    Dim myPath as string=Server.MapPath("someUrl")
    Using webp As WebP = New WebP()
        Dim myImg as Bitmap = webp.Load(Path & "testimg.webp")
    End Using
End Sub
```

I get the error:

Unable to load DLL 'libwebp_x86.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
In WebP.GetInfo
In WebP.Load

So it looks like the DLL files are in the wrong location. I have also tried /bin/Release/ and the root (/) but with no success. So how can I solve this problem?

***Additional note:** Since my other code is Visual Basic, I had to translate the .cs file (with a tool) to be able to place it in the App_Code folder along with the other .vb files. The error I’m getting doesn’t seem to be caused by a mistranslation, but if I’m right, the only way I can test the original C# code is to create another application folder. I would have to request that as I don’t have admin rights.

Comment: they belong in the debug folder

Comment: Both `/bin/debug` and `/debug` don't work either.

Comment: windows looks up dlls in all specified folder including the start folder, check during debugging the start folder and place the the dll

Comment: This question concerns a web server, which is not my own computer.

Comment: you need to depploy the asp with all necessary dll to the web server see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: The documentation says: "The wrapper is in safe managed code in one class. No need for external dll" However kernel32.dll is mentioned (imported) in the code file. Which confuses me.

Comment: `No need for external dll` It sounds like they mean 'no external *.NET* DLLs needed.' In other words, no external references that you need to worry about providing. `kernel32.dll` is, of course, a Windows-provided library.

Comment: Alternatively there's [this wrapper](https://github.com/XuPeiYao/WebPWrapper), which you may wish to consider. It has a NuGet package, so things are much easier, and it seems to have been updated more recently.

Comment: I wanted to integrate this into my VB.NET web application. I don't think this alternative can do that.